# Ash size particle dependency of initial coal particle size in fluidized bed combustors

Tags: chemical-engineering, combustion

I'm looking for information on coal ash size in fluidized beds. How dependent is it on the initial coal particle size? Would I expect ash from 5mm coal particles to be significantly larger than ash from 0.1mm coal particles? Or does the abrasion from fluidization cause the ash size to become small no matter what. Also, I'm not talking about ash that is vaporized and then reformed (fly ash), but just the mineral ash component of the coal itself.

Also does anyone know of any good literature on ash size?

Answer (score 1):

Put "Lurgi coal gasifier" into search , it will bring up many references . It will take some sorting to find fluid bed particle size. " Sasol" may also bring up information.